# Is this git scenario going to create a merge conflict on remote origin?

Tags: git, github

We have two branches, `master` and `development`, and two remote teams have a local copy of `development` that they are actively working on.

If I add three new files to `development`, the remote team edits three existing files to `development`, and we both merge to github are we going to see merge conflicts?

My main concern is that the files that they edited and the same files that are unedited on my machine are being pushed which will cause the merge issue.

Ideally, we are going to want to utilize git-flow but we are taking steps in this direction.

Comment: This should not cause a merge conflict if none of you touched the same files. If all of yours are new and their files are old, you should be totally free from merge conflict. Regardless, you are going to run into merge conflicts eventually and you shouldn't be scared of them. It's usually relatively easy to sort out.

Comment: Understood, thanks!